# add values in a store function laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a store function to create Ticket

```
          $ticket=new Ticket;
          $ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
          $ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
          $ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
          $ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
          $ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
          $ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
```

i to introduce a column where it stores total tickets which will be regular_quantity and vip_quantity

like

```
    $ticket->total= add ($vip_quantity,$regular_quantity);
```

how do i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no add function for sum in laravel you have to do it manually like

```
$ticket->total= $request->input('regular_quantity') + $request->input('vip_quantity');
```